# In a new class I got Target Unreachable, identifier ' ' resolved to null

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf

I have a project with Spring, JSF and Hibernate.
This project has been developed for 2 months. There are a lot of modules that work.
I created ManagedBean in a new package and made reference to it from a xhtml, but I got the "very common error:"

```
Target Unreachable, identifier 'someName'  resolved to null
```

So I searched and searched for this error and I realized that my configuration is correct. 
I copy my class to another package and now ... it works.

Anybody knows why is this?

Comment: What package was the first package? The default package?

Comment: No. The first package is something like:
    com.framework.comun.presentacion.controller
The new package is:
    com.sistema.comun.presentacion.controller

Comment: And i realize that the problem is when I create a package.
If i put my class in a old package it works. If I create a new package i get the error. And I make clean and a re-deploy in my Glassfish 2.1

Comment: Are the beans managed by JSF or Spring?

Comment: By Spring:
    @Scope(value = "session")
    @Controller("theBean")

Comment: Okay, that'll be a Spring issue, not a JSF issue.

Comment: At least i now know that maybe this is the way to find the issue ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what was the problem!

In my applicationContext.xml, i defined

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.framework.comun" />
```

So my annotation in the class that is in

```
com.sistema.comun.presentacion.controller
```

will not be recognized!

Thanks

Comment: Well done! That might be *the* answer to lot of other unanswered questions which I've seen before here related to Spring+JSF and exactly that exception message.